# Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'

Tags: node.js, npm

Any time I try and run any "npm" command, I get the error below around not being able to find the config for npmcli.

```
    Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
    - C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
    - C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
    - C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\olive\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\npm.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli-entry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

So far, I've tried:

- Uninstalling, Deleting all node packages and reinstalling them.
- Installing NVM (I have a Windows 10 machine)
- Playing around with the Path value.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using nvm, and it just blew up when I tried to run build on a React project.

Comment: I finally got it to work by updating nvm from 1.1.9 to 1.1.11 (the latest) and installing React 18.2.0 to exactly match what was in my package.json (not sure which one actually fixed the issue though, haha). I hope you find your answer!

Comment: Just as an update, fixed the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling node twice again. Not sure really what the difference was but it ended up resolving the majority of issues. 

That being said, the app is breaking all over the place now so bit more fun in store!

Comment: Fixed this very issue by upgrading nvm to 1.1.11, uninstalling node `nvm uninstall 20.9.0` then reinstalling the same version via the updated nvm, `nvm install 20.9.0`

Comment: Thanks @theINtoy, I solved this issue using your way. I asked the same thing and got downvoted, so thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 18):

Download the latest version of NVM.

On windows, for me this was here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

The latest version at the time of writing was 1.1.11

Exact steps were:

- Install nvm@1.1.11 via the `nvm-update.exe` download, on the link above
- `nvm uninstall 18.17` (or which ever version was failing)
- `nvm install 18.17`